# Every bounded, increasing sequence in F has a least upper bound in F $\Rightarrow$ least upper bound property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to answer a question regarding completeness of an ordered field. I'd like to show that the above holds. I know that these two things are closely related, but I am struggling to see the property of the first part that ties them together. I'd appreciate any suggestions for properties given by the first part that might help obtain the implication.

Comment: HINT: Show that if every bounded, increasing sequence in $F$ has a least upper bound, then $F$ is Archimedean, and use that to show that $F$ has the least upper bound property.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But are there not fields that are Archimedean without having the least upper bound property? The rationals as one case.

Comment: But the rationals don’t have the sequential upper bound property, either. You’ll have to use both the sequential upper bound property and the fact that $F$ is Archimedean, just as one does in proving that $\Bbb R$ has the least upper bound property.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see. So the aim here is to use the sequential upper bound property (for a sequence), and the archimedean property, to show that a similar property holds for sets in $F$? This property is the least upper bound property.

Comment: Yes, you use the seq. lub property in an ordered field to show that the field is Archimedean, and then you use all of that to show that it has the lub property.